# Enhancing javascript to execute faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a script that adjusts the height of the  `div data-role="content"></div>` to be that of the window, minus the height of the footer and header. Everything runs fine but when a page is loaded via ajax into the DOM, I get a little flicker while the content area's height is set

```
    <script>

      (function() {
        var fixgeometry = function() {
          /* Some orientation changes leave the scroll position at something
           * that isn't 0,0. This is annoying for user experience. */
          scroll(0, 0);

          /* Calculate the geometry that our content area should take */
          var header = $(".ui-header:visible");
          var footer = $(".ui-footer:visible");
          var content = $(".ui-content:visible");
          var viewport_height = $(window).height();

          var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();

          /* Trim margin/border/padding height */
          content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
          content.height(content_height);
        }; /* fixgeometry */

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(window).bind("orientationchange resize pageshow", fixgeometry);
        });
      })();



</script>
```

Its really noticible when its tested on a mobile device and it caused my images, which are percent based, to take a moment, then adjust after the script has run. Here's a link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KL2uS/3/) 
Is there anyway to optimize this script so that the flickering effect is gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use javascript when **`CSS`** is more then enough, not to mention faster option.

There an easy solution for your problem, give your div with a **`data-role="content"`** a class name or an id. For example lets say you gave it id = **content**, then this **`CSS`** will stretch your content div:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 40px;
    left : 0;
}
```

Bottom and top is set to 40px to compensate for header and footer.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/45/

Basically if javascript is not used in this case there will be no flickering. This method is also used when **`Google maps API v3`** is used with jQuery Mobile, you can find it **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)** if you want a proof.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that post before but didn't it would apply to my situation. Seeing the JSfiddle definitely made it clear it would help.